# Prolog query not returning the expected result

Tags: prolog

For university exam revision, I came across a past paper question with a Prolog database with the following structures:

```
% The structure of a media production team takes the form
% team(Producer, Core_team, Production_assistant).
% Core_team is an arbitrarily long list of staff structures,
% but excludes the staff structures for Producer and
% and Production_assistant.
% staff structures represent employees and take the form
% staff(Surname,Initial,file(Speciality,Grade,CV)).
% CV is an arbitrarily long list of titles of media productions.

team(staff(lyttleton,h,file(music,3,[my_music,best_tunes,showtime])),
[staff(garden,g,file(musical_comedy,2,[on_the_town,my_music])),
staff(crier,b,file(musical_comedy,2,[on_the_town,best_tunes]))],
staff(brooke-taylor,t,file(music,2,[my_music,best_tunes]))).

team(staff(wise,e,file(science,3,[horizon,frontiers,insight])),
[staff(morcambe,e,file(science,3,[horizon,leading_edge]))],
staff(o_connor,d,file(documentary,2,[horizon,insight]))).

team(staff(merton,p,file(variety,2,[showtime,dance,circus])),
[staff(smith,p,file(variety,1,[showtime,dance,circus,my_music])),
staff(hamilton,a,file(variety,1,[dance,best_tunes]))],
staff(steaffel,s,file(comedy,2,[comedians,my_music]))).

team(staff(chaplin,c,file(economics,3,[business_review,stock_show])),
[staff(keaton,b,file(documentary,3,[business_review,insight])),
staff(hardy,o,file(news,3,[news_report,stock_show,target,now])),
staff(laurel,s,file(economics,3,[news_report,stock_show,now]))],
staff(senate,m,file(news,3,[business_review]))).
```

One of the rules I have to write is the following:

> Return the initial and surname of any producer whose team includes 2
>   employees whose CVs include a production entitled ‘Now’.

This is my solution:

```
recurseTeam([],0).

recurseTeam[staff(_,_file(_,_,CV))|List],Sum):-
    member(now,CV),
    recurseTeam(List,Rest),
    Sum is Rest + 1.

query(Initial,Surname):-
    team(staff(Surname,Initial,file(Speciality,Grade,CV)),Core_team,Production_assistant),
    recurseTeam([staff(Surname,Initial,file(Speciality,Grade,CV)),Production_assistant|Core_team,Sum),
Sum >= 2.
```

The logic I have here is that I have a recursive predicate which takes each staff member in turn, and a match is found only if the CV list contains the production 'now', and as you can see it will return the Initial and Surname of a Producer if at least 2 employees CV contains the 'now' production.

So, at least as far as I can see, it should return the c,chaplin producer, right? Because this team has staff members who have CV's which contains the 'now' production.

But when I query it, e.g.

```
qii(Initial,Surname).
```

It returns 'false'.

When I remove the "member(now,CV)" predicate, it successfully returns all four producers. So it would seem the issues lies with this rule. Member is the built-in predicate for querying the contents of lists, and 'CV' is the list structure that is contained within the file structure of a staff structure.

Any ideas why this isn't working as I had expected?

Any suggestions on what else I could try here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need one more clause for the `recurseTeam` predicate, namely for the case that the first argument is a non-empty list, but its first element is a `file` structure that does **not** contain `now`.

In the current version, `recurseTeam` simply fails as soon as it encounters such an element in the list.

One possible solution is to add the following third clause for `recurseTeam`:

```
recurseTeam([staff(_,_,file(_,_,CV))|List],Sum):-
    \+ member(now,CV),
    recurseTeam(List,Sum).
```

Alternatively, one can use a cut `!` in the second `recurseTeam` clause after `member(now,CV)` and drop `\+ member(now,CV)` in the third clause. This is more efficient, since it avoids calling `member(now,CV)` twice. (Note, however, that this is a [*red cut*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cut_%28logic_programming%29) – the declarative and the operational semantics of the program are no longer the same. Language purists may find this disturbing – "real programmers" don't care.)

Comment: Would you be able to illustrate what you mean by indicating what clause I need? Apologies, but I didn't fully understand your answer.

Comment: Am I right in saying that what you mean is that when the recurseTeam predicate encounters a file structure that doesn't contain 'now', it fails right away? 

If that's correct, how do I prevent it from doing that?

Comment: @CiaranG: by adding an extra clause, as Uwe already said. Hint: how would you implement `member/2`?

Comment: I don't know your prolog course. Did your instructor introduce the "cut" `!`? If yes, I would insert a cut after `member(now,CV)` in the second clause and add a third clause in which `recurseTeam` is called recursively without incrementing `Sum`. If the cut has not been introduced in your course, you can also solve the problem using `not(member(now,CV))` in the third clause for `recurseTeam`.

Comment: So in other words, I need a stopping case so that it continues to recurse through the provided list of staff without incrementing the Sum, right? Would you be able to edit your original answer to show how that would look contained within recurseTeam predicate?

(the course made reference to the importance of a stopping case like the empty list case for the recurseTeam predicate that I have, but I'm not really sure how to implement it with the member predicate).

Comment: If you use `not` (or equivalently, `\+`), the third clause starts with `recurseTeam([staff(_,_file(_,_,CV))|List],Sum) :- \+ member(now,CV),...`. I leave the remainder to you.

Comment: I think I get you now. I added a third clause which is almost identical to the second one, except that Sum isn't incremented when the 'now' production isn't found in a staff member structure. If you don't mind I'll add the solution to your original answer so that you (and anyone else interested) can check it out. Cheers!